# best practices for generic constant in crystal lang

Tags: crystal-lang

How to define constants depended on generic type parameters in a generic class/struct, or any other way to allow sharing instantiated constant between instances of the class instantiated by the same type argument?

Like this

```
class Generic(T)
  CONST = [] of T
end
```

I also tried `class variable` but seems not to work, which simply bound on uninstantiated type `Array(T)`.

```
class Generic(T)
@@const = [] of T
end
```

Comment: maybe use a macro?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot for now because it would be ambiguous what you refer to with `Generic::CONST` then.

See for a discussion on this related to aliases in the following issue and it associated ones: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/1920

Comment: well, then any other approach to implement the same function?

Comment: I think you generalized your question a bit too much, try to describe your actual problem in a new question :)

Comment: Actually every real problem for me has been solved by some way. While I still believe the generalized problem indeed makes sense, that "share something 
as constant between those instantiated class".